# unable to draw an arc (circle) in canvas element

Tags: javascript, html

The problem i am facing is whenever i am setting the canvas.width and canvas.height explicitly in  my code i am unable to draw an arc via the arc method but when i dont mention the canvas.width and canvas.height i am able to draw it my code is as follow:-

```
import Paddle from '/src/paddle.js';
import InputHandler from '/src/input.js';


let canvas = document.getElementById("gamescreen");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const GAME_WIDTH = 800;
const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

canvas.width = GAME_WIDTH;
canvas.height = GAME_HEIGHT;

let paddle = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
let lastTime = 0;
new InputHandler(paddle);

//just a demo to draw an arc (and it does not work)
context.beginPath();
context.arc(10, 10, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
context.stroke();
function gameloop(ts){
    let deltaTime = ts - lastTime;
    lastTime = ts;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    paddle.update(deltaTime);
    paddle.draw(context);
    // context.drawImage(ballImage, 10, 10, 16, 16);
    requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
}
gameloop();
```

Comment: Should this code run in a browser?   Does it need Paddle hardware?  Where does paddle.js and input.js come from?

Comment: yes this code should be run on the browser.I have a paddle.js file and input.js and these implement the Paddle and InputHandler classes.

Comment: i got the solution for this as i am refresshing the frames evry time a new frame is brought up each time so if i wanted to draw something on the canvas i should mention it in the game loop